# How can I create a command to remove non-consecutive duplicate lines?

Tags: external-command, shell

I'm trying to remove (non-consecutive) duplicate lines in a file I have loaded in vim (without sorting them). In several places on the web I've found the nugget `awk '!x[$0]++'` as a pipe command that will do this, and indeed if I run this from my shell directly, i.e. `cat myfile | awk '!x[$0]++'`, it works as expected.

However, in vim, I've tried selecting some lines in line-wise visual mode, then typing `:'<,'>!awk '!x[$0]++'`, and I get an error of `cannot read file /tmp/nvimQFXXXX/31`.

My guess would that in some way my syntax is not quite right, and maybe I need to somehow escape some of the characters? I've tried `\` to escape various characters though, and I can't figure it out. I've looked in the help, but I don't see anything about escaping characters.

Bonus points if you can wrap this up in a mapping and/or function; that's my end goal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [:h :range!](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Arange%21)

```
            Filter {range} lines through the external program
            {filter}.  Vim replaces the optional bangs with the
            latest given command and appends the optional [arg].
```

The second `!` is replaced with last shell cmd, I guess it expand to some command that read
the temp file, escape it should work:

```
'<,'>! awk '\!a[$0]++'
```

Now wrapper it in a `command` and `map`:

```
vnoremap <leader>uu :UnsortUniq<cr>
command -range UnsortUniq <line1>,<line2>! awk '\!a[$0]++'
```

This can also be done without `awk`, although it's ugly compared to `awk`:

```
let g:d={} | g/^/ if has_key(g:d, getline('.')) | d | else | let g:d[getline('.')]=1 | endif
```

It gets uglier if you wrapper it in a command that support range:

```
command -range UnsortUniq2 let g:d={} | <line1>,<line2>g/^/
      \ if has_key(g:d, getline('.')) | d | else | let g:d[getline('.')]=1 | endif
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When I run `:%!awk '!x[$0]++'` in my vim, I get `E34: No previous command`.

I fixed it by escaping the `!` (see `:help :!`).

Mapping:

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/uniq.vim
function uniq#operator(type, ...) abort
  let l:visual = a:0
  if l:visual
    '<,'>!awk '\!x[$0]++'
  else
    '[,']!awk '\!x[$0]++'
  endif
endfunction

" ~/.vim/plugin/uniq.vim
nnoremap U :set operatorfunc=uniq#operator<CR>g@
vnoremap U :<C-u>call uniq#operator(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

(The key `U` is somewhat arbitrary. Replace at your leisure.)

This follows my [operator](https://github.com/benknoble/vimsort) [plugins](https://github.com/benknoble/vimpbcopy) format, and defines a new operator. It works with any motion, though of course will always be linewise. It also works with visual mode.

Comment: This is great, excellent that you wrapped it up in an operator too. I've accepted the other answer as it provided a command, but yours is obviously very useful for anyone who prefers an operator approach.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to get Vim to handle all the necessary escaping for you by calling [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29). If you pass in a non-zero value for its second argument, this will escape characters in a manner suitable for passing as a command line argument to a `!` command or filter:

```
:exe "'<,'>!awk" shellescape('!x[$0]++', 1)
```

You can wrap this into a command that takes a range (or defaults to the entire file) like this:

```
command -range=% RemoveDups execute '<line1>,<line2>!awk' shellescape('!x[$0]++', 1)
```

And you can invoke this command from a visual mode mapping like this:

```
xnoremap <leader>rd :RemoveDups<CR>
```

Comment: Cool. That's actually the original question I had, thanks.

Comment: Adding `silent!` in front of it also helps